# How can I solve this board communication problem with my Arduino Nano?

Tags: c, arduino, raspberry-pi, microcontroller, arduino-ide

It has the ATMega328P chip on it. I'm constantly trying to upload some code to it but I'm still getting errors. Everything in the IDE is selected as it should. Board type, processor and port.
Also, drivers are up to date.

Though, I'm still getting errors like:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x52
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x52
```

or

```
Device busy.
```

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: you have older IDE and new Nano or new IDE and old Nano and you didn't select "328p old bootloader"

Comment: Have you checked which COM port are you using?

Comment: @Juraj thank you, not choosing the Old Bootloader seemed to have been the problem.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I checked and it was the right one, thanks.

Comment: Info header is wrong(wrong board setting !) or `reset` got wrong timing(on_start_loading)!

Comment: Unrelated: you can check on quora dot com. But honestly: use a search engine first. There are for sure many people out there asking that question, and I am sure that many other people put together some content for them. You see, the most important skill of a software developer is to do research by himself. Don't expect others to draw the map for you. Try to make your own steps instead.

Comment: @GhostCat, sure, thanks!